# How can I build a muscular body if I am skinny

Tags: muscle, workout, muscle-gain, health

I’m 18 y.o. My height is 6 feet and my weight is about 150 pounds. Nevertheless, I look very skinny. Muscles of my torso and arms are weak and small. However, my legs look normal.
I tried to go to the gym a year ago, but it had a little effect on me. Somehow I’ve gained about 8 pounds since then but I’m still not glad with my body. What should I do to become muscular?
Information about my current lifestyle:
6-8 hrs of sleep, as I am a student living in a dorm;
2-3 meals a day (in a canteen or bought in a shop)

I’m ready to changes!

Comment: If you're trying to put on weight, you have to increase calories. "2-3 meals" is probably not enough. Try increasing the amount you eat overall, as well as putting emphasis on getting enough protein (about 1g of protein per lb of body weight). If you want to build muscle, including some sort of resistance training is the efficient way to do this. Can't speak to how you should improve your workouts without information about what you are currently doing or have tried etc.

Comment: My advice would be to increase workout frequency and volume, even if this means reducing intensity (i.e., 10 sets of 15 reps would not be uncommon). Being an ectomorph often places one at a hormonal disadvantage for muscle and weight gain (*relative* to endo/mesomorphs) and so you would need to find a way to "force" your body to develop the musculature you desire, *without* relying as much on your innate hormonal capacities. This is why workout "intensity" would have be reduced -- you just might not really get that much "mileage" out of it!